# Como detectar fraude através de um campo de texto?

Tags: algoritmo, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Devo fazer um programa de contratação de serviços simples com avaliação do serviço após concluído e lidar com fraude nessa contratação. Fraude nesse caso seria um servidor que criar múltiplos perfis que contratam ele e dão avaliações para aumentar sua reputação no site sem ele ter realmente feito o trabalho, e isso incluí um campo de texto onde terá uma descrição do atendimento e um campo de nota. Então a minha duvida é como eu posso lidar com fraude de forma simples nesse tipo de programa?

Seria bom se tiver um não supervisionado para isso, pois não precisa de dados de treino e teste. O sistema levará em consideração informações de quem contratou quem, quantos contratos de serviços um servidor possui não concluídos e o tempo que o contrato foi iniciado e quando terminado

Comment: Não existe mágica. Algo “simples” será ineficiente pois esse processo exige um connunto de técnicas. Contudo, deve avaliar os critérios da los

Comment: existem muitos campos de texto nessas avaliações?

Comment: "Ao pesquisar eu só encontro métodos complicados de aprendizado de maquina [...]". Pois é. Sinto lhe informar, mas é bem por aí mesmo. Esse tipo de detecção de fraude se baseia na identificação de atividades fora do comum, de forma que você não tem mesmo como fugir da análise de padrões comportamentais (seja usando métodos estatísticos ou regras de decisão, por exemplo). Se você tiver exemplos de transações que são fraudes, talvez seja possível treinar uma Rede Neural simples. Dá uma olhada no [Scikit-Learn (em Python)](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html).

Comment: @pmargreff, as avaliações tem apenas um campo de texto e uma de nota para o serviço de 0 até 5.

Comment: Entendo que será aprendizado de maquina mesmo então, dentre eles acharia que seria mais simples fazer qual? Seria interessante uma forma não supervisionada para isso, não precisar de uma base de dados labelados.

Comment: "O sistema levará em consideração informações de quem contratou quem, quantos contratos de serviços um servidor possui não concluídos e o tempo que o contrato foi iniciado e quando terminado" Esse parágrafo já demonstra pra você que dificilmente vai ter como fazer isso de forma não-supervisionada.